# What tense is "I have never been so hungry"?

Tags: present-perfect

What tense is "I have never been so hungry."

I can guess that it is present perfect continuous but it doesn't have verb+ing.

Or the verb might be "feeling" like, I have never been feeling so hungry. But is this sentence still correct if we drop the "feeling" verb.

Comment: It is simply present tense. Don't confuse tense and aspect.

Comment: "have been" is present perfect of to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is it wouldn't be present perfect continuous, which requires rather exact periods of time (e.g. yesterday, a year ago, when I was a teenager...).

It is, however, present perfect, which does allow for unspecific expressions such as never, ever, before etc.

There's a bit of context missing in your sentence though (not that it particularly matters in this case), as it can be taken like:

> Wow, look at that poor homeless person digging for food in the bin. I
>   have never been so hungry [as to do that].
>
> I can hear my stomach growling. I have never been so hungry [before].